# get the null value from the table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 tables meeting ,user and user_role.I want to get the value if the also null if I choose blank. `$_REQUEST['created_by_user_role'] is Array ( [0] => AM [1] => IS [2] => Mktg [3] => sales user [4] => Blank )` when blank in array I want to get the meeting id `1,2,3`

Example table data

```
meeting
 id created_by_name 
 1   a
 3
 2   b

user
 id user_name user_role
  1  a         1
  2  b         2

user_role
id user_role
 1    role_1
 2    role_2
```

Code

```
<?php
$meeting_details = DB::table('meeting')
    ->leftJoin('users as users_created', 'meeting.created_by_name', '=', 'users_created.user_name')
    ->leftJoin('user_roles as role_created', 'users_created.user_role', '=', 'role_created.id');

if (count($_REQUEST['created_by_user_role'])) {
    $filter_created_by_user_role = DB::table('user_roles')
        ->whereIn('roles', $created_by_user_role)
        ->pluck('id')
        ->toArray();
}

$meeting_details = $meeting_details->whereIn('users_created.user_role', $filter_created_by_user_role);

if (in_array('Blank', $request['created_by_user_role'])) {
    $filter_created_by_user_role[] = null;
    $meeting_details = $meeting_details->whereNull('users_created.user_role');
}

$meeting_details = $meeting_details->select('id')->get();
```

my above query returns

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please add more details and context.

Comment: Also, please share more details about what you've tried to resolve your problem

Comment: @user3386779, Is the relationship between _'users'_ and _'roles'_ a _one-to-many_ OR a _many-to-many_?. It appears like your tables aren't properly normalized. Please read about [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). In addition, your column names are confusing at best. Please read about [Laravel naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions). Beyond that, it's not clear what you want exactly.  Lastly, share your **database schema**.

Comment: @user3386779, You say you have a table _'user_role'_ yet your queries use _"user_roles"_ instead as the table name. ????